# ArcGIS Server Map Service - Best Way To Visualize Coincident (Identical) Point Features

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, cartography, overlapping-features, map-service

I have an ESRI Map Service serving out several point layers with 10k+ point features.  Because of these high feature counts, I use a dynamic map service where a symbolized image is generated on the server, and then rendered in the map clients (in this case, javascript map).  Using Feature layers is not feasible - as the feature counts 'pop' the browser.

Within these point layers, there can be a single location (coordinate) with many features.  For example, in one layer, 36 features share the same coordinate.  So, in the map, I only see 1 'dot' at this location.  But these 36 features have different attribute properties that control symbolization.  For example, lets say 16 features have status of 'on' (green) and 16 feature have status of 'off' (red).  Right now, you only see the color of the last rendered feature.

Is there some type of magic trick I could use to explode these features out from the common origin?

Comment: Great question. How often do the features change?

Comment: The features themselves dont change per se, but features are added/deleted regularly.  So, any solution needs to be dynamic - cant require running some ArcTool after every update.

Comment: Something like the ClusterLayer in this example? https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/layers_point_clustering.html

Comment: No, that wont work for 2 reasons.  One - there is no distinction between features in the cluster.  I need to be able to see all features.  Two - that is a client side feature.  Bad things happen in the browser when you try to load a feature layer with 10k points.